# wp_enqueue_ scripts

Tags: jquery

I've searched high and low for the answer - the codex on `wp_enqueue_script` seems pretty simple.

The problem is when I add my custom excerpt script to my functions file, register and then enqueue it (set to place in header), the source is displayed in the header as:

```
<script src="http://www.olliedaw.co.uk/wp-content/themes/DawRefrigerationMilkTanks/js/excerpt.js" type="text/javascript">
```

Which looks correct in firebug, but it still comes up with a 404 error when I look at the script in firebug as if it can't find the file!

File name is right, and is in the right place but still cant get it to load???

```
themes/Daw Refrigeration Milk Tanks/js/excerpt.js
```

Comment: 1. Having spaces in the URL makes everything more confusing, I would suggest removing the spaces from the folder name.
2. excerpt.js returns a 404 error, make sure that file is properly named and exists in that directory.

Comment: You could also control the file permissions.

Comment: Rename your theme directory by removing spaces

Answer (score 3):

No, that's not right.  Your script is located at `http://www.olliedaw.co.uk/wp-content/themes/Daw%20Refrigeration%20Milk%20Tanks/js/excerpt.js` and you're enqueueing `http://www.olliedaw.co.uk/wp-content/themes/DawRefrigerationMilkTanks/js/excerpt.js` ... those are not the same file!

This happens often when you have spaces in your file names and directories.  Either remove the spaces or explicitly escape them as `%20` when you queue them with `wp_enqueue_script()`.

Answer (score 1):

I would not use spaces in your path to the js file. Some older browsers will not work with spaces or even using %20.

I would recommend renaming your theme folder with dashes or underscores.